# vAxis Single line label in angular-google-chart

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, ng2-google-chart

[image]

I am using angular-google-chart to implement google chart in my angular app, when the y axis labels (marked with red color) is too long it in coming up in three lines then showing "..." , i want only one one line to show up instead of 3, how this can be achieved. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in the chart's configuration options, you can add more room for the labels using the `chartArea` option...

```
var options = {
  chartArea: {
    left: 600
  }
};
```

you can also reduce the font size using the following `vAxis` option...

```
vAxis: {
  testStyle: {
    fontSize: 8
  }
}
```